# Passing raw params to angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a small mobile app blog with ionic and angular but when i try to make a resource query with manually injected params i have a bad url string. meaning angular is not passing my syntax correctly or i am making a bad mistake.

Here is my code

```
angular.module('starter.posts', ['ionic','ngResource'])

    .factory('Post', function ($resource) {
        return $resource('http://example.org/wp-json/:params');
    });

app.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, Post) {
    "use strict";
    /* Items for left side menu. */
    $scope.posts = Post.query({params: "posts?filter[posts_per_page]=3"})

})
```

and the error log show the bellow error

```
http://example.org/wp-json/posts%3Ffilter%5Bposts_per_page%5D=3 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

which simply means that it did not translate the url correctly. How can i fix this so the url can be in the bellow format

```
http://example.org/wp-json/posts?filter[posts_per_page]=3
```

I am new to angular trying to simulate an entire wordpress blog with angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure the right syntax by using the code below,

```
 Post.query({'filter[posts_per_page]': 20, 'page' : $scope.pageNum}, function (data, responseHeaders)
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like this, passing a js object in:

```
usersFactory.get = function (request) {
                var operation= $http({url: urlBase, method:'get', params:request });
```

perhaps you should add posts to your resource url

```
$resource('http://example.org/wp-json/posts:params');
```

and pass an object like this

```
var filter={};
filer.posts_per_page=3
```

in as your params

Comment: i am trying to prevent the use of post in the resource so i can use the same method for other things like categories and tags